# Why does useEffect React Hook not work properly with dependency?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm working at a **React Web App** with `Fullcalendar`. **I think one does not need to know Fullcalendar in order to answer this question**. It's rather a matter of React understanding.

Long story short, `Fullcalendar` has an api that refetches any `events` from a given `source`.
In my case, my `source` is `state.events`, iniated with `useState`. I only want to `refetch`, when my `state` changes. All good so far. However, at the first initial render, `Fullcalendar` is not able to fetch anything.

```tsx
const OverviewPage: React.FunctionComponent<IOverviewPageProps> = (props) => {
    const calendarRef = useRef<any>();
    const [sourceAPI, setSourceAPI] = useState<any>(undefined);
    const [state, setState] = useState<State>({
        externalEvents: [],
        events: []
    });
   
useEffect(() => {
         if (calendarRef.current !== undefined) {
            let calendarApi = calendarRef.current.getApi();

            if (sourceAPI === undefined) {
                const source = calendarApi.addEventSource(state.events);
                source.refetch()
                setSourceAPI(source);
            } else {
                sourceAPI.refetch();
            }
        }
    }, [state])
return (<div>
           <FullCalendar
               ref={calendarRef}
               //other props
           />
        </div>)
;
```

Now, as you can see, as long as I don't have the `reference` of the `calendar`, I can't iniate the `calendarApi`. And as long as I don't have that api, I can't `refetch`.
I do have to mention, when I take away the `useEffect` dependency (`state`), I no longer face an issue with fetching the events (even on the initial render). However, that causes other issues in my code that I wasn't able to fix, so I rather prefer to fix it with `useEffect`.

**Update**

It was requested to explain more in depth, what is happening in the code.
`Fullcalendar` needs a `source` of `events` (calendar tasks). To provide this `source`, one has to iniate it before render, which I'm doing here in `useEffect`

Checking, if the `reference` to the `element Fullcalendar` already exists to prevent a render error

```tsx
if (calendarRef.current !== undefined) {//...}
```

Checking, if a `source` was already added. If no, iniate a `source` by using `Fullcalendar's` api. `.addEventSource` adds a source that contains an `array` of `objects` (`events`) - in this case `state.events` - and returns a `Fullcalendar Source` so that I can interact with it later (e.g. `refetch`).
`.refetch()` simply takes the content of the `source` and (re-)renders them on the calendar (so in other words the content of `state.events`).
I then store this `Fullcalendar Source` in a `React State` so that I can interact with the same source later again, without having to reiniate it again.

```tsx
 if (sourceAPI === undefined) {
                const source = calendarApi.addEventSource(state.events);
                source.refetch()
                setSourceAPI(source);
            }
```

If a `Fullcalendar Source` is already existing, apply the `refetch` call again.

```tsx
else {
        sourceAPI.refetch();
}
```

There's really not more to say about `Fullcalendar`. I was suspecting the issue in `React State management` and that I'm doing something wrong there (with `useEffect`).

Comment: Can you provide the Code for your fetching functions?

Comment: it's not my function, it's provided by `Fullcalendar` as an api call.

Comment: What does this calendar API do with the values you are passing it from React? What does `addEventSource` and `refetch` do? What are you expecting to happen? CAn you more precisely explain the issue? Can you "walk" us through the code and explain each piece and also provide the exact steps to reproduce any issues you are seeing?

Comment: @DrewReese I've updated my post as requested. I was expecting some sort of error in the way I'm handling `useEffect` hence not explaining `Fullcalendar` in depth.

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is that you are updating the `state.events` state but the calendar code isn't seeing any updated state? As far as I can tell, this appears to be a stale enclosure over the `state.events` value that was passed to `calendarApi.addEventSource`.

Comment: @DrewReese What I don't understand, I thought when using `useEffect` with `dependency`, the corresponding `useEffect` is only triggered once the corresponding `dependency` (the `state`) has been updated completely right? I checked now with `console.log` and basically on startup of the program/page, it triggers `useEffect` twice and both times `calendarRef` is `undefined`. Once started, switching to another page and back, `calendarRef` is no longer `undefined` and the `source` is mounted / events rendered.

Comment: `useEffect` hook with dependency, the effect's callback is called at the end of the initial render, and any time any of the dependencies update. There was a change to the `React.StrictMode` component in React 18 that mounts the component twice and keeps the result of the first mount. See [Ensuring reusable state](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state). This isn't what I'm referring to though. The state is only passed to the calendar code once when it is instantiating a source. Can you link some documentation on this `Fullcalendar` library?

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks for your help, very much appreciated. Here's a link to the library in terms of `React`. Scroll down to the chapter `Calendar API`: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react - And here's a link in regards of mounting `sources`: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-source

Comment: Do you just need to call `calendarApi.addEventSource` each time the `state` updates? I don't quite understand the source stuff since it doesn't appear to be used at all.

Comment: @DrewReese I finally was able to figure it out. I answered my question in case someone else has a similiar issue in the future. You're right, `.addEventSource` is not important each time `state` updates. It's just important that `.addEventSource` is triggered once and max once, so that `.refetch()` can be called when the `state` does update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244495/discussion-between-scorpia-and-drew-reese).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying out multiple different approaches, I finally managed that `Fullcalendar` also renders `events` on the first initial render.
This might be helpful for people in the future, facing the same issue with `React` and `Fullcalendar`

```tsx
const OverviewPage: React.FunctionComponent<IOverviewPageProps> = (props) => {
    const calendarRef = useRef<any>();
    const [sourceAPI, setSourceAPI] = useState<any>(undefined);
    const [state, setState] = useState<State>({
        externalEvents: [],
        events: []
    });
useEffect(() => {
        if (sourceAPI === undefined && calendarRef.current !== undefined) {
            const calendarApi = calendarRef.current.getApi();
            const source = calendarApi.addEventSource(state.events);
            setSourceAPI(source);
        }
    });
   
useEffect(() => {
        if (sourceAPI !== undefined) {
            sourceAPI.refetch();
        }
    }, [state]);

return (<div>
           <FullCalendar
               ref={calendarRef}
               //other props
           />
        </div>)
;
```

Pay attention that the first `useEffect` is triggered every time while the second one is only triggered when there was a change in regards of its `dependency`. This way, the `source` is initiated for sure, which it appeared to be the main problem with the privious code (`calendarRef.current` was always `undefined` on initial start/render)